# точность GPS координат android

Tags: android, gps, геолокация

Имеется приложение на андройде что определяет координаты,

```
double lat = location.getLatitude();
double lon = location.getLongitude();
```

результат выглядит примерно так:

```
// lat = 56,8053733333333 
// lon = 31.8458366666667
```

Проблема заключается в том что на той же точке координаты, но определенные приложением на apple iPad, будут более точные:

```
// lat = 56,8054799130715
// lon = 31.8458472788668
```

Разница довольно ощутима, и заметно что в результатах андройда на седьмой цифре после запятой идет явная ересь. Причем не только на этой конкретной географической точке, но и в других местах тоже, меняются только цифры с седьмого знака после запятой, идут: 777777 или 333333 или 111111 и т.п.

Есть ли какой-то способ получить более точные координаты на андройд устройстве (максимально подобные apple'у), или все зависит от конкретного андройд устройства и его производителя?

Comment: Всё зависит от GPS-датчика, зашитого в девайс

Comment: да видимо от датчика что установил производитель устройства. Проверил на трех устройствах, телефон Sony, планшет Lenovo, планшет Samsung. Только последний показал точные координаты с 13 знаками после запятой.

Comment: А самые слабые это Alcatel. Там разрабосы по несколько километров бывают=)

Comment: ok, приму к сведению спс